# appending a jquery object throws invalid argument in IE 

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append, invalid-argument

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin that will clone a form to an iframe then submit a form.  It is a hack to fake an ajax file upload. I also know there are plugins like this already, but none that I have trie meet my needs.  I have a problem appending a jQuery object to anything in IE. (I am running IE 7.0)  I have tried FF and it works perfectly. I am also using jQuery 1.3.2 min. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(function($){

$.fn.extend({ 

//pass the options variable to the function
formUploader: function(options) {

    //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
    var defaults = {
        onSubmit: function(){ return true;},
        onComplete: function(){ return true;}
    }

    var settings =  $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).submit(function(){
        var id = "asdfasda";
    $(document).find('body').append('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" />');

    //this should be a form
    var curEl = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        //fails in IE but not in FF
        $("#"+id).contents().find("body").append($(curEl).clone());
    },250);
    return false;
        });
    });

    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you have an element with ID "asdfasda" in your page?

Comment: The line of code which you've identified is doing multiple operations.  You might get better help if you narrow down which operation is actually throwing the error.

Comment: I create an iFrame with the ID 'asdfasda'.  At some point it will become a unique ID.  I can append html but not jquery objects.  For example: $("#"+id).contents().find("body").append("<form>stuff here</form>") will work but $("#"+id).contents().find("body").append($("<form>stuff here</form>") will not.  Appending html wont copy the value of the file input which is why I can't just append the html, it has to be cloned.

I also simplified my code to make it easier for people to help me which is why there are multiple operations on one line, but I know its the append function.

Answer (score 1):

> clone a form to an iframe then submit a form

Difficult to see from the example, but if you are trying to clone an element into a different document, that's not allowed by the DOM standard. Nodes created by one document cannot be inserted into another document. The contents of an iframe are a different document.

The way to do it should be to use `document.importNode()`:

```
var iframe= document.getElementById('myiframe');
var idoc= iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var form= document.getElementById('myform');
idoc.body.appendChild(idoc.importNode(form, true));
```

But IE doesn't support importNode at all. Then again, IE already supports XMLHttpRequest, so that may not be an issue. What browsers are you implementing this for, that don't support `XMLHttpRequest`? Careful: browsers that old/broken may also not support `importNode`, or even jQuery!

Note that if you want to use jQuery's convenience methods to create nodes in the iframe's document, you must have a second copy of jQuery loaded by a <script> tag in the iframe, which you call via the other document's copy of `$`. Each jQuery instance is tied to the document that included it; a jQuery wrapper from one document cannot be passed to another document.

```
var inp= idoc.$('<input type="hidden" name="thing" />');
inp.val(thingvalue);
idoc.$('#myform').append(inp);
...
```

Comment: You don't actually need to have a second jquery loaded into the iframe.  You can just grab the document from the iframe and pass that into the jquery function that generates the nodes.

var doc = $('#theiframe').contents().get(o); // this is the document from the iframe
$('<form/>', doc);  // this creates the new form node so that it belongs to the iframe.  Then you can add it with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the jQuery Form plugin, it lets you submit file input field using an iframe, [check it here](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started)

Perhaps you can re-use the same rather than re-inventing the wheel.